# System.DirectoryServices.Protocols Paged get all users code suddenly stopped getting more than the first page of users

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

So here is the code using S.DS.P to get all users very quickly in pages of 500 at a time..

```
public List<AllAdStudentsCV> GetUsersDistinguishedNamePagedResults( string domain, string distinguishedName )
        {
            try
            {
                NetworkCredential credentials               = new NetworkCredential( ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AD_User"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AD_Pass"] );
                LdapDirectoryIdentifier directoryIdentifier = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier( domain + ":389" );

                List<AllAdStudentsCV> users = new List<AllAdStudentsCV>();

                using (LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(directoryIdentifier, credentials))
                {
                    string filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";
                    string baseDN = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AD_DistinguishedName"];

                    string[] attribArray = {"name", "sAMAccountName", "objectGUID", "telexNumber", "HomePhone"};

                    List<SearchResultEntry> srList = PerformPagedSearch(connection, baseDN, filter, attribArray);

                    if (srList.Count == 0) return null;

                    foreach (SearchResultEntry entry in srList)
                    {
                        <...snip a bunch of code to filter out bad users by CN...>

                                users.Add( user );
                            }
                            catch ( Exception ex )
                            {
                                throw;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return users;
            }
            catch ( Exception ex )
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

private List<SearchResultEntry> PerformPagedSearch( LdapConnection connection, string baseDN, string filter, string[] attribs )
        {
            List<SearchResultEntry> results = new List<SearchResultEntry>();

            SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest(
                baseDN,
                filter,
                System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree,
                attribs
                );

            PageResultRequestControl prc = new PageResultRequestControl(500);

            //add the paging control
            request.Controls.Add(prc);
            int pages = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                pages++;
                SearchResponse response = connection.SendRequest(request) as SearchResponse;

                //find the returned page response control
                foreach (DirectoryControl control in response.Controls)
                {
                    if (control is PageResultResponseControl)
                    {
                        //update the cookie for next set
                        prc.Cookie = ((PageResultResponseControl) control).Cookie;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                //add them to our collection
                foreach (SearchResultEntry sre in response.Entries)
                {
                    results.Add(sre);
                }

                //our exit condition is when our cookie is empty
                if ( prc.Cookie.Length == 0 )
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine( "Warning GetAllAdSdsp exiting in paged search wtih cookie = zero and page count =" + pages + " and user count = " + results.Count );
                    break;
                }
            }
            return results;
        }
```

It works perfectly on DEV and on Prod, but suddenly stopped working on the QA webserver when it talks to the QA AD server. it only returnes one page and then stops.
If I point DEV to the QA AD server it works correctly...

It was working before Feb 2012, last time I tested in QA, and definitely was broken in place by March 7, 2012

Can anyone think of anything that would cause this behavior? perhaps a windows update? I've had one jack this product up before...

I'm reasonably convinced that it's not the code or the configuration...as it works on so many other combinations... it's netowrk/securiyt/os related.. but I can't figure out what changed.

Any Help is appreicated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Had the exact same issue where no pages were returned after the first one.

Here is what I found to fix the problem:

```
PageResultRequestControl pageRequestControl = new PageResultRequestControl(500);

SearchOptionsControl soc = new SearchOptionsControl(System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchOption.DomainScope);

request.Controls.Add(pageRequestControl);
request.Controls.Add(soc);
```

No idea what the SearchOptionsControl does, but since I added this, AD returns all the expected objects.

Comment: Marked as answers, even though that's not how we fixed it... We wound up having to rebuild our entire QA server afresh to fix the "issue" as nobody know what had changed. After the rebuild it worked fine again.

Comment: Okay mucho cudos to you, this behavior reappeared and we used this code to fix it and it worked!

Comment: My IT guys just did some ad schema work to upgrade Microsoft CRM edition (upgraded to CRM 2013) and I started seeing missing Cookie issue from PageResponseControl. Used this code to fix. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This line solves the issue (connection is LdapConnection) ->

`connection.SessionOptions.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOptions.None;`

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/17957bb2-15b4-4d44-80fa-9b27eb6cb61f/pageresultrequestcontrol-cookie-always-zero?forum=csharpgeneral